# Cannot connect to TP-MR3220

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

Yesterday, I plugged in the lAN flylead between my router, the TP-MR3220, and type the IP 192.168.0.1, and was promptly asked for a password, which I had long forgotten. So, I thought a quick factory reset would reset it to 'admin' again.

Thing is, I can no longer reach the device. It's like it's changed IP address. I even went and bought a new flylead, in case that one was faulty. What could cause this sudden withdrawal? Oh yes, after the reset, only the power light on the very left was on, and a lock-looking light on the very right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source [TL-MR3220 3G/4G Wireless N Router User Guide](http://www.tp-link.com/Resources/document/TL-MR3220_v2_User_Guide.pdf)

> The default IP address of the 3G/4G Wireless N Router is 192.168.0.1.

So the IP address should not have changed after the factory reset.

[image]

**After the reset, only the power light on the very left was on, and a lock-looking light on the very right.**

This means:

- Your router has power.
- The last light on the right (with the lock) indicates the status of WPS (Wi-Fi Protected Setup). If it is on this means a wireless device has been successfully added to the network

However:

- From your description the second light from the left (SYS) is **not** on => **The Router has a system error**

Comment: Yes after a power reset, the second from left light is always flashing calmly.

Comment: Are you connecting with a lan cable? Into which port? Are any other leds on or flashing?

Comment: LAN cable into LAN port, not the WAN port as I first did with no results at all. Only very left light, and very right light.

Comment: **The Router has a system error**